# Edit to correct Latin names not possible

Tags: discussion

I wanted to correct some Latin names because the species names also began with a cap (only genus should start with a cap, species not). But when I changed it, I got a message that I have to edit at least 6 characters...

Why is this stupid limitation? Why such a rule? Don't you want correct Latin names in this site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like to edit and I know that frustration. Sometimes you just want to correct one or two letters and that annoying 6 character message pops up. I think it might be because edits goes through the "suggested edits" queue, and they don't want tiny edits bothering the reviewers.

Once we hit the [1,000 rep privilege](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), we can edit as many or few characters as we want. We're considered trusted enough to understand the system, and our edits stop passing through the review queue. (It also means we can become the reviewers, which is a fun way to help newer users!)

Please don't stop making the edits you do now, especially the Latin names, because those are very confusing. You just need to make sure they're more than 6 characters.

In case you haven't seen it, the [How does editing work?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/editing) page in the Help Center is very informative.

> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!
>
> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks

Correcting Latin names or other technical things are absolutely in that category! One of the easiest of the above choices is adding links. While you're correcting the spelling, you can add a link to further information about that plant. That easily uses up your character limit, and helps readers learn.

I suggest paying close attention to the question titles. They often lack detail. We have a lot of "What is this plant/flower/tree?" questions. Those can be greatly helped by adding descriptors. For instance, "What yellow flower is this?" is not as beneficial as "What is this tall, yellow, perennial flower with a brown center?"  We also prefer titles to be written as questions. For instance, "Tall yellow and brown perennial?" should also be changed to "What is this tall, yellow, perennial flower with a brown center?

Finally, if the question you're editing includes some form of greeting or thanks, deleting that is encouraged. It's very hard for me to do because people are just being nice! If the person puts their name in a post, definitely delete that. Their username is already on their question, and it leads to their profile. The explanation for that is on [this page](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) in the Help Center.

If you have further questions or need clarification, leave me a comment and I'll see what I can do!